# How to shift multiple lines of code in IntelliJ by a single space?

Tags: intellij-idea

Am trying to shift multiple lines of code in intellij IDEA by a single space using Tab shortcut but it always shifts by 4 spaces rather than a space. I have tried Edit > Convert Indent > To spaces but to no avail.

How do you shift multiple lines of code by a single space without messing with the default configuration for the file?

Comment: Use multiple carets (Double Alt+Up/Down) and space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Andrey already suggested, I would use the [Multi Cursor](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/intellij-idea-13-1-rc-introduces-sublime-text-style-multiple-selections/) feature that has been around since intellij idea version 13.

I like the `Add selection on Next Occurrence` feature very much. It  helps me to edit multiple lines very fast.

This screenshot shows the action in the `Settings -> Keymap` screen.

[image]